# How do you use switch statements in a for loop?

Tags: c, ascii

Recently, I've started learning C, and a project I'm doing rn is a program that converts any phrase into an ASCII title style artpiece. The way I want to do this is like a TV, scanning from top left to bottom right of the screen. To do this, I need to get a tally of all letters in that phrase. Right now I'm doing it with this snippit:

```
printf("Let's make your text an ASCII title!\n");
printf("Please input your phrase:");
scanf("%s", &phrase[20]);


for (i=0;i<=20;i++) {
    switch (phrase[i]) {

        case 'A':
        aCounter++;
        continue;

        case 'B':
        bCounter++;
        continue;
        
    }
}

printf("A: %d", aCounter);
printf("B: %d", bCounter);
```

However, I've tried using the break; continue; and even leaving it empty, but it simply exits the for loop without any warning. Also, it doesn't return the correct number of (in this example) A, and B. How do I fix this?

Comment: Read up on `scanf()` and its use... You want something like `scanf(" %s", phrase );`

Comment: `scanf("%s", &phrase[20])` reads a string of characters and puts it in `phrase` starting at position 20. Then the `for` loop checks the items of `phrase` from positions `0` to `20` inclusive. If this is all your code then, most probably, `phrase` contains garbage on positions `0` to `19`.

Comment: Should check the characters from position `0` of `phrase` until the end of the string, not until position `20`. `for (i = 0; phrase[i] != 0; i ++)`

Comment: I have never seen anyone use `continue` in a switch-statement, so keep using `break`. Also, making random changes to the code and hope it will work better, hardly ever works. And when it actually does work occationally, it is often because there are now 2 bugs that work in different direction.

Comment: Fe2O3 and axiac, thanks for the help, that turned out to be the issue! Also BoP, I did try using break; in the switch statement as I usually do, but it didn't work, so I thought that was could be the problem (like it exiting the for loop or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `continue;` ignores `switch` statements when going up: it will use the innermost `for`, `while` or `do ... while`.

A `break;` will use the innermost `switch`, `for`, `while` or `do ... while`.

If neither `break;` nor `continue;` jump to where you want, you can use `goto` instead.

Comment: Recommending the use of `goto` in C is ... unusual. However, in the OP's case, the two `continue` statements will do what they want, once they have fixed the issue of the input.

Answer (score 0):

'like a TV, scanning from left top left to ...', no, but this will return, the input, its ascii equiv  and count. (I am just a learner, hope this is useful, if 'switch' answers are the only option pls, disregard)

```
char userInput[99];
int charCount = 0;
printf("please enter a phrase!\n");
fgets(userInput,99,stdin);

for(int i = 0; userInput[i] != '\0'; i ++){
    if(userInput[i]!='\0'){
            charCount++;
        printf("%c\n",userInput[i]);   //returns user input up to the '\0' 
        printf("%d\n\n",userInput[i]); //also returns the ascii value of new line char (10)
        }
        }
        printf("CharCount was %d\n",charCount);
```